# How do you average values in a Do Until Loop?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to write a code to average values in a particular column. I have a table with 5 columns, Column number 2 has the date/time, and column number 5 has a measurement. There are over 500 lines of data, one for each minute of the test, and my goal is to write a code to take all the data and average it down to 15 minute intervals.

I attempted this by starting my active cell on the first line of the table, and inserting a row, offsetting the active cell to take the value of the row below (date/time of minute 15) and move it into the newly inserted row. Then, to average the 15 rows of data for column 5 and input it into the inserted row in column 5. I attempted to do this with an iterative process but I cant get the macro to average the value.

Could someone please assist? - new to VBA, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
'Averages PID Values to 15 min intervals

Sub Make_Data_Box()
' Databoxes_1 Macro

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        Dim loc As String
        
        loc = ActiveCell.Value
        Dim iter_1 As Integer
        iter_1 = 1
        Do Until ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(iter_1, 0).Value
            iter_1 = iter_1 + 1
        Loop
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
        ActiveCell.Offset(iter_1, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(-iter_1, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(iter_1 - 1, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("ActiveCell:ActiveCell - 14"))
       ' ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ActiveSheet.Range("ActiveCell:ActiveCell+14"))
        ActiveCell.Offset(-iter_1 + 1, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(iter_1 + 14, -2).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Never use `.Select`. Instead directly set values with statements like `Range("A1").Offset(5, 0).Value =  Range("B1").Offset(5, 0).Value` for example.

Comment: You refer to multiple cells using the `.Resize()` modifier. For example the average value of 10 cells below `G2` is `WorksheetFunctions.Average(Range("G2").Resize(10,1))`

Comment: Is each row a minute? And what happens if 15 leaves a remainder from the total number of rows? I would read into an array and sum for 15 loops then divide and store e.g. in a dict , reset sum to zero then repeat. You can test with mod for when to reset. Write out dict values as an array to sheet at end with .keys

Comment: My goal with this code was to not need to refer to exact cells - I was attempting to write it as an iterative process since the number of rows each time this is done will vary. Assuming every table has a number of rows divisible by 15, would editing my code to incorporate the resize comment work? Assuming G2 as the starting cell, something like:
```WorksheetFunctions.Average(Range"G2-iter_1".Resize(15,1))```

The above used to average 15 rows below G2, and starting the first iteration at iter_1=0 with G2 the initial active cell. Would that work or is that not how iterations work in VBA?

Comment: Does it have to be VBA?  You can do it with a formula and pivot table.  If that's of use, I can post a suggestion.  Also, it sounds like you are trying to insert rows into your existing data, meaning if the macro goes crazy, you have "corrupted" your data.  Wouldn't you want to record the result separately?

Comment: I dont know what a Pivot table is - if that achieves the same result I wouldn't mind trying that. I'll look into Pivot tables on my own but any suggestion would be appreciated. 

I was only trying to insert rows because that seemed like necessary for writing the macro to me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```vb
Sub Make_Data_Box()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngAvg As Range
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim AvgCol As Long
    Dim DataCol As Long
    Dim AveragePeriod As Long
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or specify sheet you want
    
    ' Get reference to Data Values range, this assume there are Headers in Row 1, Data from Row 2
    DataCol = 5 ' Column number containing data
    Set rngData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, DataCol), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, DataCol).End(xlUp))
    
    ' Column to put Average in
    AvgCol = 6 ' adjust to place Average where you want it
    AveragePeriod = 15 ' Take average of this number of rows
    
    For idx = AveragePeriod To rngData.Rows.Count Step AveragePeriod ' fill every AveragePeriod cell with average
        rngData.EntireRow.Cells(idx, AvgCol) = _
          WorksheetFunction.Average(rngData.Cells(idx, 1).Offset(1 - AveragePeriod, 0).Resize(AveragePeriod, 1))
    Next
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Or, if you want to insert a row for the AVERAGES, work from the bottom up

```
Sub Make_Data_Box2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngAvg As Range
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim AvgCol As Long
    Dim DataCol As Long
    Dim AveragePeriod As Long
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or specify sheet you want
    
    ' Get reference to Data Values range, this assume there are Headers in Row 1, Data from Row 2
    DataCol = 5 ' Column number containing data
    Set rngData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, DataCol), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, DataCol).End(xlUp))
    
    ' Column to put Average in
    AvgCol = 6 ' adjust to place Average where you want it
    AveragePeriod = 15 ' Take average of this number of rows
    
    For idx = (rngData.Rows.Count \ 15) * 15 To 1 Step -AveragePeriod ' fill every 15th cell with average
        With rngData.Cells(idx, 1)
            .EntireRow.Insert
            .Offset(-1, AvgCol - DataCol) = _
              WorksheetFunction.Average(.Offset(-AveragePeriod, 0).Resize(AveragePeriod, 1))
        End With
    Next
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```